# Why does Kusama allow executing arbitrary XCM programs but not sending them?

Tags: xcm

When looking at Kusamas's `pallet_xcm::Config` we can see that it allows [only the council](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/eed45cfe22d5d1d66d0d149f4a0656f90976ad8b/runtime/kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L177) to use **send** arbitrary XCM messages while [it allows everyone](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/eed45cfe22d5d1d66d0d149f4a0656f90976ad8b/runtime/kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L180) to **execute** arbitrary XCM messages.

1. Why is sending a more privileged operation than executing?
2. Can't a user send arbitrary XCM by executing a wrapping instruction like `InitiateTeleport` anyways?
3. What is it a user cannot do when they can only **execute** but not **send**?

Comment: hey Alexander, do you think this question was properly answered already. I am also interested in the rationale behind this.

Comment: I was asking around internally at Parity but probably didn't asked the right people, yet. I have a vague idea but I don't want to speculate here. We just leave it open for now until somebody answers with confidence.

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer authoritatively on the 1st or 3rd, but maybe answers to the 2nd question may help illuminate.

2. The answer is no, but let's list out all of the instructions that allow a user to provide an arbitrary XCM blob as a parameter and sends it onward to another destination:

```
InitiateTeleport
InitiateReserveWithdraw
DepositReserveAsset
ExportMessage // XCMv3 instruction
```

For the top 3, every time the XCM blob is sent to the intended destination, a `ClearOrigin` instruction is inserted right before executing the XCM blob, making it impossible for the XCM blob to run any privileged operations. Take for instance, the `WithdrawAsset` instruction and look at how it is executed:

```
WithdrawAsset(assets) => {
    // Take `assets` from the origin account (on-chain) and place in holding.
    let origin = self.origin_ref().ok_or(XcmError::BadOrigin)?.clone();
    for asset in assets.into_inner().into_iter() {
        Config::AssetTransactor::withdraw_asset(&asset, &origin, Some(&self.context))?;
        self.subsume_asset(asset)?;
    }
    Ok(())
},
```

Right on the first line, we see that it's trying to get a reference to the local origin register. Since the origin register has been cleared out via `ClearOrigin`, this line will fail and we won't be able to send and execute such an instruction via `InitiateTeleport`, `InititateReserveWithdraw` or `DepositReserveAsset`.

In addition, the two instructions `InitiateTeleport` and `DepositReserveAsset` requires the destination to whitelist the sender as a safe teleporter/reserve, adding another layer of security against arbitrary XCM executions.

For `ExportMessage`, there is a validation function that is called during the execution of it, which is controlled by the message exporter, so the responsibility of ensuring that nothing weird gets sent via the bridge is up to the bridge itself.